# Moq - How to create a mock that implements multiple interfaces at the same time

Tags: c#, moq

I have a method that expects an object implementing two interfaces:

```cs
public class MyClass {
    public void Do<T>(T myObj) where T : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB { ... }
}
```

I am using Moq 4.10.1 to try to create a mock of this object. The [documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#advanced-features) shows how to work with multiple interfaces:

```cs
// implementing multiple interfaces in mock
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
var disposableFoo = mock.As<IDisposable>();
// now the IFoo mock also implements IDisposable :)
disposableFoo.Setup(disposable => disposable.Dispose());

// implementing multiple interfaces in single mock
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Name).Returns("Fred");
mock.As<IDisposable>().Setup(disposable => disposable.Dispose());
```

However, following these examples, I could only get a mock that implements one of the interfaces at a time, but not both:

```cs
var mockA = new Mock<IInterfaceA>();
var mockB = mockA.As<IInterfaceB>();
instance.Do(mockB.Object); // Error: mock only implements IInterfaceB, but not IInterfaceA
```

Is there any way to create a mock implementing both interfaces at the same time?

Edit: I don't want to create a third interface that combines the others only to allow testing.

Thanks

Comment: Saying "I don't want to do... <an existing solution>" is not a valid response by the way. Unless you have a technical reason for not doing that, then you have your answer.

Comment: @peflorencio if you don't want 3rd `interface` you could do the trick with `dynamic`. Just cast `instance.Do((dynamic) mockB.Object);`. The point is that mock under the hood create proxy which already implements additional `interface`.

Comment: @DavidG I don't think that this question, as it is right now makes it a duplicate of that question. It could have an answer as "There is no other way rather than making a third interface" or "There is another way...". It could have a different answer, and the will to find a different approach than the one that is already known for a problem should be enough.

Comment: @meJustAndrew How is a question titled *How to create a mock that implements multiple interfaces at the same time* not an exact duplicate of a question titled *Mocking generics that implement multiple interfaces*? If you want to add that answer, you can do it on the marked duplicate.

Comment: @DavidG I am just saying that there are a lot of questions here on SO that are looking for another solution to a problem that was solved in a given way before and they are not always marked as a duplicate. You may be right to mark this one as a duplicate, but imposing somebody to accept an existing solution as you did in your first comment is not the best attitude. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @meJustAndrew That is how this site works though. If OP wants another answer to the question, then that answer needs to go on the marked duplicate. And the way to generate traffic to *that* post is to put a bounty on it.